# jpa inheritance - reuse an entity in several others

Tags: java, jpa, entity, reusability

I am new to jpa and wonder how I have to realize this. I want to use an Entity called Address in several other Entities.

Car entity:

```
@Entity
public class Car 
    @Id
    private String id;

    private  String licensePlate;

    @ManyToOne
    private Address address;

    public Car() {
    }

    /* Getter and setters */
    ....
    ..
```

Person entity:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "address", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Address> addresses;

    public Person() {
    }

    /* Getter and setters */
    ....
    ..
```

Address entity:

```
@Entity
public class Address {

    @Id
    private String id

    private String streetAndNumber;

    /* Now what?????? */
    private Car car; // would fit for car
    private Person person; // would fit for person

    // But what would be fitted both?
```

I searched the internet to find a solution. But, most likely to my lack of knowledge. I couldn't find something understandable.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually no need to make all relations bidirectional, it's a best practice to prefer unidirectional relationships in a model whenever possible, see [Domain Driven Design Quickly](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/domain-driven-design-quickly).

In this case Address does not need to know of all the entities that it's associated with. Also consider making the address a Value Object (see DDD quickly) using the `@Embeddable` annotation.